# Using UPDATE with different amount of fields and Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to understand prepared statements and wnat to make a prepared statement for this:

```
// UPDATE GAME PLAYERS DATA IN DB // 
mysql_query("UPDATE ".$prefix."_gameplayer SET player_tiles='$playertiles'
                                             , player_draws='$udraws'
                                             , player_turn=0
                                             , last_draw_type=1 
                                WHERE fk_player_id=$playerid AND fk_game_id=$currgame");

// UPDATE GAME OPPONENTS DATA IN DB //  
mysql_query("UPDATE ".$prefix."_gameplayer SET player_turn=1
                                             , last_draw_type=2 
                                WHERE fk_player_id=$opponent AND fk_game_id=$currgame");
```

I was thinking of doing this but am wandering how to make sure not to update some fields in the second statement:

```
$stmt->prepare("UPDATE ".$prefix."_gameplayer SET player_tiles='?'
                                             , player_draws=?
                                             , player_turn=?
                                             , last_draw_type=? 
                                WHERE fk_player_id=? AND fk_game_id=?");

$stmt->bind_param('siiiii', $playertiles,$udraws,0,1,$playerid,$currgame);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_param('siiiii', ?,?,1,2,$playerid,$currgame);
$stmt->execute();
```

In the second statement I dont want to update the 2 first fields??? Can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just run 2 separate queries like you did with mysql. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Prepared statements have fixed parameters. If you want to execute two queries with different parameter count, you need to prepare two statements - one for each update type.

Long answer: you may use dirty hacks, like creating a CASE statement on the optional parameters, like

```
SET x=CASE WHEN something THEN ? ELSE x END
```

but is it really worth it? It makes the query a lot more complex, and harder to maintain. And what happens, when you need to modify just one of the queries?

Comment: So, if I can't use an prepared statement to replace like 2 inserts a normal mysqli query is just as good?

Comment: Your mysql_query examples are vulnerable to SQL injection, while the prepared statements are not.

Comment: But nothing gained in terms of connections and executing time?

Comment: So if I refresh the same page it has an effect?

Comment: No, since you will prepare your statement again.

Comment: So to gain anything in regards of connection and executing time I should use stored procedures?

Comment: stored procedures are used to run complex operations on the sql server - they won't make a difference for simple updates.

Comment: So in regards of max_user_connections I don't gain anything using Stored Procedures!?! Sorry for my ignorance!